# Using squid to access local dev sites from iOS device fails

Tags: ios, proxy, virtualhost, squid

In order to access dev sites hosted on my laptop (apache virtual host) from an iOS device for testing, I want to use squid.

I installed squid by getting squidman (http://squidman.net/squidman/). In squidman interface, I set http port to 8080; provided my iOS device's IP in the Clients tab; and commented out the `http_access deny to_localhost` line in the Template tab (used for building squid config). I then made sure my iOS device and my laptop are connected to the same network, and entered my laptop's IP address and the port number (8080) in the HTTP proxy settings of my iOS device.

Last time, this has worked on-and-off. This time, it doesn't work at all (iOS browser shows "cannot connect to the server" or "cannot connect to the proxy" when trying to access one of the local dev sites). I restarted everything just in case, which didn't help. Squid access logs are empty, so I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this. My other option is to use Charles proxy in the same way, but I would really like to get this free alternative working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the network (ping issue between devices on the WiFi); this was probably also the reason why squid has worked on-and-off for me last time.

If you have the same problem: try squid (or Charles) on a different network (eg. home network if you previously tried to set it up at work) to check whether the problem disappears.